# eslint Parsing error: ecmaVersion must be 3, 5, 6, or 7

Tags: node.js, eslint

I'm using the eslint 3.18.0 and node 7.7.4. I'm setting the ecmaVersion to 8 ([per the documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)), but getting this error: Parsing error: ecmaVersion must be 3, 5, 6, or 7. Is ecmaVersion 8 not supported? If it is why am I getting this parsing error?

Here's the full .eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 8,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "quotes": ["error", "single"]
    }
}
```

Comment: ecmaVersion 8 is supported, so it must be something else. Verify your local version of eslint (or if you are running global version, verify that).

Comment: IIya, that was it. I was using an older global version of eslint. Thanks! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ESLint currently supports versions 3, 5, 6 (es2015), 7(es2016) and 8(es2017). If you are having trouble enabling es2017, verify that your ESLint installation is up to date. es2017 was added to ESLint as of v3.6.0 that was released on Sep 23, 2016. Verify global/local version (whichever you are using).

Comment: how does one verify the global or local version, please?

Comment: Local: ```npx eslint --version```. Global: ```eslint --version```

Answer (score 12):

The ecmaVersion is not valid; I recently installed eslint and ecmaVersion was set to 13

"parserOptions": {
"ecmaVersion": 13
},

The valid versions are 3 to 12 or latest. I use 'latest' :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing the following

1. Deleted the node-modules directory & package-lock.json
2. npm install
3. Changed the ecmaScript version in .eslint file

It worked for me.